# C deep copy struct with pointer

Tags: c, struct, deep-copy

I'm new to C and need to solve the following problem.

I have a project reading a small bmp (512x512) image. I've managed to change colors and have it mirrored (both horizontal as vertical). Though I now need it to turn -90°. The function that I can't manage to work is the **deepCopyBitmap()**.

I keep getting the following error on `*copy->raster[i]` :

> `indirection requires pointer operand ('PIXEL' (aka 'struct _pixel') invalid)`

**ROTATION (512x512)**

```
typedef struct _pixel {
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
} PIXEL;

typedef struct _bitmap {
    char file_path[PATH_MAX+1];
    char magic_number[3];
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned char application[5];
    unsigned int start_offset;
    unsigned int bitmapHeaderSize;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned short int depth;
    unsigned  char* header;
    PIXEL* raster;
} BITMAP;

void rotate(BITMAP* bmp) {
    int i;
    int j;
    PIXEL* originalPixel;
    BITMAP* originalBmp;

    deepCopyBitmap(bmp, originalBmp);

    for(j=1; j <= bmp->height; j++) {
        for(i=1; i <= bmp->width; i++) {
            originalPixel=getPixel(originalBmp->raster, bmp->width, bmp->height, j, i);
            setPixel(bmp->raster, bmp->width, bmp->height, (bmp->width + 1 - i), j, originalPixel);
        }
    }                  
}

void deepCopyBitmap(BITMAP* bmp, BITMAP* copy) {
    *copy = *bmp;
    if (copy->raster) {
        copy->raster = malloc(sizeof(*copy->raster));
        for (int i = 0; i < copy->height; i++) {
            copy->raster[i] = malloc(sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
            memcpy(copy->raster[i], bmp->raster[i], sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
void deepCopyBitmap(BITMAP* bmp, BITMAP* copy) {
    copy = malloc(sizeof(BITMAP));
    *copy = *bmp;
    if (copy->raster) {
        size_t total_size = copy->height * copy->width * sizeof(PIXEL);
        copy->raster = malloc(total_size);
        memcpy(copy->raster, bmp->raster, total_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `copy->raster` supposed to be pointer to array with 512 elements of pointers to arrays with 512 PIXEL elements (= jagged array), or pointer to single array of 262144 PIXEL elements? I ask, because the double malloc seems to suggest the former, but datatype `PIXEL*` the latter.

Comment: `copy->raster[i]` is value, not pointer. Because the `raster` is  1D array.

Comment: The raster is a 1D array, with 262144 PIXEL elements

Comment: You don't allocate memory for `originalBmp` in `rotate` function, which means that `*copy = *bmp;` in `deepCopyBitmap` results in undefined behaviour (=quite likely crash). It would be logical if `deepCopyBitmap` would also `malloc` memory for the actual `BITMAP` structure.

Comment: @user694733 I've added copy = malloc(sizeof(BITMAP));. Though at run, I get Segmentation fault: 11;

Comment: I can't really tell you what is wrong. There is simply too much information missing. For the next time, see how to provide [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only allocate one `PIXEL` here:

```
        copy->raster = malloc(sizeof(*copy->raster));
```

However, you need at least `copy->height` `PIXEL`s for this iteration to work:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < copy->height; i++) {
```

Here, you only allocate one `PIXEL` again:

```
            copy->raster[i] = malloc(sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
```

But, you probably intend to copy `copy->width` `PIXEL`s, not one:

```
            memcpy(copy->raster[i], bmp->raster[i], sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
        }
```

What you really want to do is allocate `copy->height * copy->width` `PIXEL`s, and copy them from the original.

```
        size_t total_size = copy->height * copy->width * sizeof(PIXEL);
        copy->raster = malloc(total_size);
        memcpy(copy->raster, bmp->raster, total_size);
```

Comment: I tried that last part, with the total_size. 
But I still need to loop over every Pixel in the copy->raster right?

Comment: Currently I get the error: RUN FINISHED; Bus error: 10; real time: 320ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Comment: @PeterVanGorp No, you should not loop over. As you can see, `memcpy` already copies all pixels with `total_size` parameter.

Comment: `memcpy` does the iterating for you.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. So it is as simply as that (see updated code above). Though while running I get the following: RUN FINISHED; Bus error: 10; real time: 300ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms